# 414 URI too long

Tags: php, post

I understand why I get this error. But I have a serious issue, as I can't seem to get it past it properly.

I'm using an API from a company named Zoho for their Recruit system. I'm using an API method that updates a record to upload a file.

https://www.zoho.com/recruit/api-new/api-methods/updateRecordsMethod.html

Initially I added the file with the rest of the data, but I would to split it up and see if it solved my error, but it didn't. My request URI is way too long.

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents($filepath);
$encodedFile = base64_encode($filecontent);

$file_data =
      "<Candidates>
        <row no='1'>
          <FL val='Vedhæft CV / Attach CV'>" . $encodedFile . "</FL>
          <FL val='Vedhæft CV / Attach CV_filename'>" . $filename . "</FL>
        </row>
      </Candidates>
      ";

$encoded_file_data = urlencode($file_data);
      $file_url = 'https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/private/xml/Candidates/updateRecords?authtoken=xxxx&scope=recruitapi&version=2&id=xxxx&xmlData=' . $encoded_file_data;
      echo strlen($file_url);
      $file_request = new WP_Http;
      $file_add_result = $file_request->request($file_url, array('method' => 'POST', 'body' => $encoded_file_data));
```

When I get the length of the URI it says 61614... this is just a sample file, it could be bigger. The way I see it, I'm forced to send data this way. Can I somehow make it shorter? I can't seem to find anything on this.

The only way I can get past it is to have a really short file, but that's not a real solution.

Comment: get has a limit, don't think post does

Comment: In the last line of code I specify the method as POST.

Comment: It's still in the URI, put it in the body of the POST request.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The way I see it, I specified 'body' as $encoded_file_data. It would seem I have misunderstood something.

Comment: You put `$encoded_file_data` in the `$file_url`. No wonder the URI is too long..

Comment: Where else should I put it? It's what I want to post. Like I said, I know why I get the error, but I don't know how to solve it.